# a two-variable cyclic power inequality $x^y+y^x>1$ intractable by standard calculus techniques

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, maxima-minima

If $x$ is in the open interval (0,1) and so is $y$, prove that $$x^y+y^x>1$$

A direct two-variable application of maxima and minima seems difficult.

Comment: There is probably a clever olympiad type proof, but I would hope somebody can ind a 2-variable calculus solution...

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose(if it's not true, change the place of $x,y$ in the following arguments) $$\dfrac{x^{y-1}}{y^{x-1}} \geq 1$$

Then we have $ (x^y + y^x)^\frac{1}{x} = (y^x (1+\dfrac{x^y}{y^x}))^\frac{1}{x} = y (1+\dfrac{x^y}{y^x})^\frac{1}{x} $

Then since $\frac{1}{x} > 1$, we have $$(x^y + y^x)^\frac{1}{x} = y (1+\dfrac{x^y}{y^x})^\frac{1}{x} \ge y(1+\dfrac{x^y}{y^xx}) = y(1+\dfrac{x^{y-1}}{y^x}) = y + \dfrac{x^{y-1}}{y^{x-1}} \geq y+1 > 1$$

since $\frac{1}{x} > 1$, we have $x^y + y^x > 1$

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Graubner and Petite Etincelle...Your solutions very satisying...however, neither uses maxima and minima in two variables, which is what I was hoping for...nevertheless I do appreciate the effort and the contribution...again, thanks

Comment: @mark You are welcome, Mark. I don't know if we can do it through simply taking maxima and minima, since there is no simple expression for the extreme value...

Comment: I am curious. Is this the source for this: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_medium;action=display;num=1213001311 ? If not, can you please point me to where you got it from? Thanks!

Comment: @Aryabhata It was too long ago, I don't remembre how I got this solution but probably not related to this link

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

let $x,y\in (0,1)$ and let $y^{\frac{1}{1-y}}\geq x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ then we have
$\frac{x^{y-1}}{y^{x-1}}\geq 1$
Now let $S=(x^y+y^x)^{1/x}$ since $\frac{1}{x}>1$ we get $(1+x)^{r}\geq 1+rx$ if $x>-1,r\geq1$ and we have
$S\geq y(1+\frac{x^{y-1}}{y^x})=y+\frac{x^{y-1}}{y^{x-1}}\geq y+1$ therefore we have $S\geq 1+y>1$ and since $S>1$ we get $S^x>1$

Comment: I want to correct one statement.  The function x^y+y^x DOES have one critical point: namely at x=y=1/e but it is a saddle point and so the function has no extreme value in the open unit square.

Comment: can you prove your statement?

Comment: Yes, the graphs of f_x=0 and f_y=0 are respectively concave down and concave up and are reflections of each other across the line y=x (by symmetry) and so cross it AT THE SAME POINT, x=y=1/e.

Comment: I am curious. Is this the source for this: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_medium;action=display;num=1213001311 ? If not, can you please point me to where you got it from? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why it's intractable by standard calculus?

If $x\geq1$ or $y\geq1$ so the inequality is obviously true.

Thus, we can assume $\{x,y\}\subset(0,1)$.

We'll prove that $x^y\geq\frac{x}{x+y}$.

Indeed, $x^y\geq\frac{x}{x+y}\Leftrightarrow f(x)\geq1$, where $f(x)=x^y+yx^{y-1}$.

$f'(x)=yx^{y-1}+y(y-1)x^{y-2}=yx^{y-2}(x+y-1)$.

Id est, $x_{min}=1-y$ and $f(x)\geq f\left(x_{min}\right)=(1-y)^{y-1}>1$.

Hence, also $y^x\geq\frac{y}{x+y}$ and $x^y+y^x\geq1$. Done!

Comment: You are right, Michael Rozenberg, that the inequality x^y\geq x/(x+y) proves it.  In fact I can prove that x^y\geq x/(x+y-xy) which improves the RHS of the of the original inequality to 1+1/(1/x+1/y-1)>1.  But, I was hoping for a TWO VARIABLE analysis using partial derivatives and showing that a necessary condition for their simultaneous vanishing is that (ln x)(ln y)=1 and  that therefore there are no critical points in (0,1)x(0,1) which means that any extreme value of x^y+y^x must occur along the boundary.

Comment: I understand you. By the way, we can prove that $x^y>\frac{x}{x+y-xy}$ by the same way. Also we can use Bernulli.