# Prove that for all $a, b > 0, a^b + b^a > 1$

Tags: functions, inequality, exponential-function

This seems an innocent inequality.
The trivial case when $a \ge 1$ or $b \ge 1$ is easy to prove:
if $a \ge 1$, then $a^b \ge a^0 = 1$.
So the hard part of the problem is when $a, b \in (0, 1)$
.

Comment: Neat question.  Since you've reduced to the case that $a,b\in(0,1)$, perhaps try assuming WLOG that $a\geq b$ and seeing if that helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319578/exponential-teaser), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009304/a-two-variable-cyclic-power-inequality-xyyx1-intractable-by-standard-calcu), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482549/a-classic-exponential-inequality-xyyx1) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381090/xyyx1-for-all-x-y-in-mathbbr-2)

Comment: Or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841064/where-does-the-premise-of-this-idea-come-from) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042080/an-inequality-concerning-a-particular-function-of-two-variables)